# How do I insert a dynamically generated element into a HTML table cell?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given the following table:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td id="resultsTable"></td>
<td>content<td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need to insert the dynamically generated table into the resultsTable cell. In JS, it is generated with

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.setAttribute("class", "resultsTable");
table.setAttribute("id", "resultsTable");
```

The table is never inserted into the cell, and the dynamically generated table impinges on the svg map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.id = 'anotherTable'
table.className = 'anotherTable'

document.getElementById('resultsTable').appendChild(table) // << Here
```